# Get a Specific Value from Serialized Data in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, serialization

I am trying to get a specific value from a serialized data in javascript that's received from **c#**  code..., the data is received correctly but am not getting the specific string i need from the serialized data... here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var desc = '<%= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(rep_desc)%>';

alert(desc);

</script>
```

I am getting something like:

```
["xxx","yyy","zzz"]
```

I've tried to use `alert(desc[0])` i receive only `[`

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes around the JSON for it to be parsed as an array instead of a string

```
var desc = <%= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(rep_desc)%>;
```

Comment: When i remove them, i get an error which is: syntax error at the end of line!

Comment: That's weird, i ran the website and it shows the result... that's great thank you.. i'll mark your answer in 8 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `var desc = JSON.parse(the string)` to get the object you want